# Azure Configuration setting that loads a directory from the physical path upon clicking app service URL

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops

I have successfully deployed an angular app in azure. However, since my folder structure in my web app contains subfolders for languages, I need to tell azure to somehow load this default directory upon url access.

Illustration:

- My URL -> abcazure.net
- When I click on it, abcazure.net/en-US gets loaded in the browser

Also note that when I access abcazure.net/en-US manually, page gets rendered; but when I access abcazure.net only, I get a **You do not have permission to view this directory or page.** error

I am aware that this can easily be done in the code but Im just wondering if this can be done in azure.

Comment: Sorry. Managed to work around this by specifying the exact file with the directory in Configuration->Default Documents:

I added en-US/index.html on top of my list and it worked like a charm

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept it, so other SO user may focus on still not resolved question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. Managed to work around this by specifying the exact file with the directory in Configuration->Default Documents: I added en-US/index.html on top of my list and it worked like a charm –